# Can't find element with XPATH despite being found in the console search bar

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to implement a program that fills certain section of a MS One page, I've been using Python and selenium for this task, I can access the webpage ok, I can send keys in the main page, but in the client's page I can't locate the elements.

I've tried:

- By.ID
- By.XPATH (xpath and full xpath)

To no avail, the code I'm using for that is:

```
sel = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='cmtx_pasaporte_i']")
sel.send_keys("198282828")
```

I get the error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='cmtx_pasaporte_i']"}
  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.75
```

But when I search the xpath in the console I find the element right away.

I'm new at python, webscrapping and everything, thanks in advance for any help.

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkvJ2.png)

Comment: could you add the url? also, are you sure that when the `find_element` line is executed the element is present in html?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the element is not located inside an `<iframe>` . If so, first switch to the `<iframe>` element, e.g. with:

`driver.switchTo().frame(index || "name" || "id" || WebElement)`

then try to locate the elements you need. Remember to switch back after you're done. [Here's](https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html) some basic info on how to handle iframes.